# Regex - Extract Words within brackets and quotes if it starts with a keyword only

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the following string:

`[The quick] brown fox [mykey*="is a  super-fast9"] animal [mykey^="that"] can run "very rapid" and [otherkey="effortlessly"].`

I need to extract the words(separated by space)  within double quotes that is at the same time within brackets that start with a specific keyword(mykey).

**So far I have:**

The quick

mykey*="is

a

super-fast9"

mykey^="that"

otherkey="effortlessly"

**But I want:**

is

a

super-fast9

that

Example Link: https://regex101.com/r/zmNse1/2

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you're doing this often within your app and it's not a one-time thing, you may want to look into writing a parser instead of using Regex.  You can use parser generators like ANTLR so it's not like you'd need to do it from scratch.

Comment: Let me double check: you need space separated values that are inside the double quotes in `[key="...."]` substrings? And want them as a flat list?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes correct...and only if the bracket starts with a specific key ...[mykey....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution offered by Wiktor is the most logical to use, but for sake of RegEx challenge see this Pattern `\[(?!mykey)[^\[]+|([^\s\[=\"]+)(?=[^\"]*\"\])`, check group #1  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lmtp8r/2)

```
\[                  # "["
(?!                 # Negative Look-Ahead
  mykey             # "mykey"
)                   # End of Negative Look-Ahead
[^\[]               # Character not in [\[] Character Class
+                   # (one or more)(greedy)
|                   # OR
(                   # Capturing Group (1)
  [^\s\[=\"]        # Character not in [\s\[=\"] Character Class
  +                 # (one or more)(greedy)
)                   # End of Capturing Group (1)
(?=                 # Look-Ahead
  [^\"]             # Character not in [\"] Character Class
  *                 # (zero or more)(greedy)
  \"                # """
  \]                # "]"
)                   # End of Look-Ahead
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, I have accepted both yours and Wiktor as answers since running your   regex in a large text is really slow, so for that case I will probably end up using Wiktor, if the text was shorter I would have used yours. Thanks very much

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez If you end up using a more efficient solution, why not tell others by accepting it?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew I actually ended up using some sort of hybrid between your answer and AlphaBravo. For the matters of simplicity and also so that this question can be useful for future readers, I've marked AlphaBravo as the official answer because is the one that is closer to the exact precise question I asked. But again, both are good, and I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

You may match the substrings you need with a relatively simple regex and capture the parts between quotes, and then split the captures with 1 or more whitespace pattern:

```
var pattern = "\\[mykey[^][=]+=\"([^\"]*)\"]";
var s = "[The quick] brown fox [mykey*=\"is a  super-fast9\"] animal [mykey^=\"that\"] can run \"very rapid\".";
var result = Regex.Matches(s, pattern)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .SelectMany(v => v.Groups[1].Value.Trim().Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result));
```

See [the C# demo](http://ideone.com/ZFMWfO).

The pattern is

```
\[mykey[^][=]+="([^"]*)"]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5Bmykey%5B%5E%5D%5B%3D%5D%2B%3D%22%28%5B%5E%22%5D*%29%22%5D&i=%5BThe%20quick%5D%20brown%20fox%20%5Bmykey*%3D%22is%20a%20%20super-fast9%22%5D%20animal%20%5Bmykey%5E%3D%22that%22%5D%20can%20run%20%22very%20rapid%22.).

**Pattern details**

- `\[`  - a literal  `[`
- `mykey` - a literal substring
- `[^][=]+` - 1 or more chars other than `[`, `]` and `=`
- `=` - an equal sign
- `"` - a double quote
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"]` - a literal `"]` substring.

Note that the captured value is trimmed from leading/trailing whitespace first (with `.Trim()`) to avoid empty values in the result. `@"\s+"` matches 1 or more whitespace chars. The `.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` splits Group 1 value with whitespaces.

Comment: If there can be `mykey="111 222"` you need to replace `+` with `*` in the regex, `\[mykey[^][=]*="([^"]*)"]`.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do what you want :
`(?<=\[mykey.?="[^]]*)[\w-]+(?=[^]]*"\])`
Demo [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5bmykey.%3f%3d%22%5b%5e%5d%5d*%29%5b%5cw-%5d%2b%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%5d%5d*%22%5c%5d%29&i=%5bThe+quick%5d+brown+fox+%5bmykey*%3d%22is+a++super-fast9%22%5d+animal+%5bmykey%5e%3d%22that%22%5d+can+run+%22very+rapid%22+and+%5botherkey%3d%22effortlessly%22%5d.)
I assumed there cannot be nested brackets. Also I didn't know what to do with the `^` or `*` between `mykey` and the `=`, so I allowed an optional wildcard.
You might need to escape the backslashes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: Since others mentioned String Parsing, I thought I'd give one implementation of that here.  String parsing options are always longer-winded, but are orders of magnitude faster than Regular Expressions.  As a guy who uses Regex a LOT, I can still say that I prefer string functions where possible.  The only complications with this answer are that you have to know what your assignment operators are, and you can't have Escaped Double-Quotes in your String Value.  I wrote it fairly verbose, though you could cut out some conditionals or shorten some lines if you wanted less bytes of code.

```
List<string> GetValuesByKeyword(string keyword, string input)
{
    var vals = new List<string>();
    int startIndex = input.IndexOf("[");
    while (startIndex >= 0)
    {
        var newValue = "";
        if (startIndex >= 0 && startIndex < input.Length - 1)
        {
            var squareKey = input.Substring(startIndex + 1).Trim();
            if (squareKey.StartsWith(keyword))
            {
                var squareAssign = squareKey.Substring(keyword.Length).Trim();
                var assignOp = StartsWithWhich(squareAssign, "=", "+=", "-=", "*=", "/=", "^=", "%=");
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(assignOp))
                {
                    var quotedVal = squareAssign.Substring(assignOp.Length).Trim();
                    if (quotedVal.StartsWith("\""))
                    {
                        var endQuoteIndex = quotedVal.IndexOf('"', 1);
                        if (endQuoteIndex > 0)
                        {
                            newValue = quotedVal.Substring(1, endQuoteIndex - 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newValue))
        {
            vals.Add(newValue);
            startIndex = input.IndexOf("[", input.IndexOf(newValue, startIndex) + newValue.Length);
        }
        else startIndex = input.IndexOf("[", startIndex + 1);
    }
    return string.Join(" ", vals).Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
}
```